# regular expression inside a cURL call

Tags: bash, curl

I have a cURL call like this:

```
curl --silent --max-filesize 500 --write-out "%{http_code}\t%{url_effective}\n" 'http://fmdl.filemaker.com/maint/107-85rel/fmpa_17.0.2.[200-210].dmg' -o /dev/null
```

This call generates a list of of URLs with the HTTP code (200 or 404 normally) like this:

```
404 http://fmdl.filemaker.com/maint/107-85rel/fmpa_17.0.2.203.dmg
404 http://fmdl.filemaker.com/maint/107-85rel/fmpa_17.0.2.204.dmg
200 http://fmdl.filemaker.com/maint/107-85rel/fmpa_17.0.2.205.dmg
404 http://fmdl.filemaker.com/maint/107-85rel/fmpa_17.0.2.206.dmg
```

The only valid URLs are the ones preceded by the 200 HTTP code, so I would like to put a regular expression in the cURL so that it only downloads the  lines that start with 200

Any ideas on how to do this without being a bash script?

Thank you in advance

Comment: What's the reason behind avoiding a bash script? Would a single pipeline be ok, or do you really need to use a single `curl` command?

Comment: Aaron, thank you for your answer… a single pipeline would more than fine as I can just execute it from the command line directly

Comment: I can't test it, but using `-f` should be enough to avoid output on 404, so maybe adding that flag and removing the `-o /dev/null` would actually be enough. (edit : no that wouldn't, all 200 URLs would be output on stdout rather than in their own file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following :

```
curl --silent -f --max-filesize 500 --write-out "%{http_code}\t%{url_effective}\n" -o '#1.dmg' 'http://fmdl.filemaker.com/maint/107-85rel/fmpa_17.0.2.[200-210].dmg'
```

This will try to reach every url and when it's not a 404 nor too large download it into a file whose name will be based on the index in the url.

The `-f` flag makes it avoid to output the content of the response when the HTTP code isn't a success one, while the `-o` flag specifies an output file, where `#1` corresponds to the effective value of your `[200-210]` range (adding other `[]` or `{}` would let you refer to other parts of the URL by their index).

Note that during my tests, the `--max-filesize 500` flag prevented the download of the only url which didn't end up in a 404, `fmpa_17.0.2.205.dmg`

Comment: The -f flag is perfect for not downloading every 404 response as a false .dmg but the -o with the #1 gives me a file of name 205.dmg instead of the name specified in the URL, so I changed it to the -O flag and now I get "fmpa_17.0.2.205.dmg" as I needed.

The --max-filesize 500 was just to experiment so I would not download the whole package every time. I just deleted it.

The only thing I can't get is the output of --write-out "%{http_code}\t%{url_effective}\n" to just show the 200 responses and not all of them even if they don't download afterwards.

Comment: @Bottaco you should be able to filter the 2xx responses by adding a  `| grep -E '^2'` after your curl call.

Comment: Thank you very much Aaron, I had already tried the grep option but I wanted to see the output right away and with the grep redirection I only see the entries when it is finished. But it is fine for what we need. Thank you very much for your help and your knowledge

Comment: @Bottacco I think this problem might be solved by adding the `-N` flag to the curl command (`--no-buffer ; Disable buffering of the output stream`). Otherwise [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe) might solve it.

Comment: I have tried the `-N` flag and it makes no difference… I am going to try the solution in the other question, but as I am using bash on macOS I think the `unbuffer` command doesn't exist, or at least there is no man entry.

Comment: Maybe try `--line-buffered` on the `grep` command too? Otherwise I don't know, sorry.