# How do I curl a URL with an unknown filename at the end?

Tags: linux, bash, curl

I'm talking to a server that creates a new zip file daily, ex: (data-1234.zip). Every day the name of the previous zip is removed and a new one is created with an incremented number, ex: (data-1235.zip). The script will be run sporadically throughout the week but it's on a lab system where the user can't manually update the name with what's on the server.

The server only has one zip file in that directory, it's just a matter of getting the correct naming convention. There is, however a "data.ini" file in the folder as well, so something just searching by first name wouldn't necessarily work. I've seen posts similar to [This question using regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51674002/regular-expression-inside-a-curl-call) but the file is currently on 10,609 and I'd rather not use expansion for potentially thousands of calls depending on access to modify the script in the coming years. I've been searching for something similar to "data-*.zip" but haven't had any luck.

Comment: Can you just fetch the directory and then parse the result for a list of links? If the directory only contains `data.ini` and your `.zip` file, that seems relatively easy.

Comment: Without showing more details, it's not clear what _specific_ technical problem is stopping you from doing this yourself. Why _can't_ you match the name with a regex like `data-[[:digit:]]+[.]zip`? _Exactly_ what have you tried, and _exactly_ how did it fail? It's not obvious to me as a reader why expansion-based approaches are unsuitable; if "potentially thousands of calls" means one per day, so what? If it means something more specific, _be clear about that_. Similarly, it's not obvious what kind of modifications you anticipate, or why using regexes would make those modifications hard.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Match it where? HTTP doesn't have a way of listing the directory.

Comment: @Barmar, sure, but the OP is linking to code that _does_ use regexes and implying that the reason they can't do that themselves is... something fuzzy I don't understand, _not_ that it's narrow and specific. And many HTTP servers _do_ provide a not-standardized-but-shared-and-parsable index format. If their server _doesn't_, they should say that explicitly instead of implying that a matching-based approach _would_ work but for some fuzzy, poorly-explained objections.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy You generally have to enable the automatic index, it's not by default. It sounds like the existing script is simply a loop that tries to download `data-1.zip`, `data-2.zip`, and so on until it succeeds.

Comment: (If we end up in a place where we keep a local data file that stores the last filename successfully downloaded and the date when it was downloaded, and work from there to predict the current name, that's very doable, but I want to see the question be explicit about requirements before we start down that road, because if we have a more client-friendly configuration, far less dubious and bug-prone solutions become feasible)

Comment: The right solution is for them to put a file on the server that contains the name of the latest zip file. You download that file, get the zip file from it, then download the zip.

Comment: Or have the server owner maintain a symlink that gets updated every time the file is replaced. Toh-may-toe, toh-mah-toe...

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I'm new to the command line as an intern, and when I tried an expansion such as data-[10000-20000].zip it seemed to be attempting to ping for every single variation in the system. The current system in place is exactly what Barmar mentioned and I was tasked with replacing it. That solution with data-[[:digit:]]+[.]zip seems like it would work though. I'll try it and mark it as solved if it works. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know what the request you're making to the server looks like, so I don't know which formats are valid in that request. What I suggested was a POSIX ERE-compliant regex, but there's no way of knowing if that's appropriate; most services don't take any kind of a regex at all.

Comment: If you included __actual code__ showing how you make the request -- what tools you're using, which things are request parameters vs instructions for those tools to iterate vs something else -- that would provide a lot more context for informed, useful answers, and at least let us make some inferences of what the server you're trying to download from looks like and how it's configured.

Comment: Okay, that context is helpful; this is a literal curl argument. No, a regex won't work there. At first I assumed you had a server that could provide a directory listing and you were trying to search through that listing. (Have you checked whether the server _is_ configured to generate automatic indexes? If it does, you've got a solution to your problem right there). (And just to lean in again on what I was saying earlier: We shouldn't be needing to assume _anything_ to understand a question: it's your job to include enough details to make it answerable)

Comment: Think about trying to switch from curl to `lftp` -- which, despite the name, _does_ act as a client for HTTP servers; if your server _is_ configured to generate an index, lftp will try to parse it, and you can use `mget`-type traditional FTP-client tools to match filenames against that index.

Comment: Thank you for the comments, I'm new to the industry but I'll try to be more clear in future posts. The actual server is some corporate endpoint no one locally seems to have credentials for, so all I have is "download.companyname.com/product/data/data-1234.zip". I tried installing lftp and using the link but it just hangs on "[Connecting...]" I was able to curl the directory specifically and I got HTML that includes the name of the file I need, so I think I should just be able to parse that and then run a second curl with the exact file.

Comment: Did you include the `https://` or similar part in the lftp command line? If you don't specify a protocol it'll try to use the ftp protocol by default, and if the server doesn't support it, that'll explain it hanging on "connecting". By contrast, `lftp https://download.companyname.com/product/data/` is more likely to work as intended. (If it _does_ connect, try running `ls`, and if _that_ works, `mget *.zip`)

Comment: Thank you! That worked, the command I'm running now is `lftp https://download.companyname.com/product/data/ -e "mget data-*.zip"` and it seems to be working great so far.

Comment: All excellent help above. Glad you have your problem sorted. I'll also recommend these resources : https://shellcheck.net . Paste your code, including `#!/bin/bash` (or other) as the first line and fix any problems flagged. Also you'll do well to read, review and take to heart the items on this page : https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info . Skip the version info at the top and head directly to the sections labeled "Before asking about Problematic code" and "How to turn a bad script into a good question" .(This advice applies to many programming idioms, not just shell scripts). Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question was solved by changing commands and running
`lftp https://download.companyname.com/product/data/ -e "mget data-*.zip; bye"`
since lftp allows wildcards in the filename, unlike curl.